# why once have empty line, grep -F -f can't work correctly?

Tags: grep

There are file a and b, and want to find common lines and diff lines.

```
➜  ~  cat a <(echo) b     
1
2
3
4
5

1
2
a
4
5
#find common lines
➜  ~  grep -F -f a b
1
2
4
5
#find b-a
➜  ~  grep -F -v -f a b
a
```

everything is ok, but when have empty line in one file, the grep can't work, see below

```
# add an empty line in file a
➜  ~  cat a
1

2
3
4
5
# content a is not common
➜  ~  grep -F -f a b   
1
2
a
4
5
# b-a is nothing
➜  ~  grep -F -v -f a b
```

why is so, why once have empty line, grep can't work correctly?

in addition, use `grep` to find common elements have another problem, e.g.

```
➜  ~  cat a <(echo) b
1
2
3
4
5
6

1
2
a
4
5
6_id

➜  ~  grep -F -f a b
1
2
4
5
6_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use comm and diff instead of grep?

to find common lines use:

comm -12 a b

to find diff line:

diff a b

Comment: you are right, use `grep` has many pitfalls. I have supplemented another example.